Save asp:Image ImageUrl as byte[]? to SQL Server database VARBINARY(MAX)
I have a page that displays an ASP:Image using C#.
Once the image is displayed, how do I update the database, saving the ASP:Image into a VARBINARY(MAX) column in my SQL Server table?
For example, if there is no image in the database upon loading, a default image is read from a file and put into the ASP:Image object. Now when I go to update the record, I need to save the ASP:Image into the database.
I have multiple options, after searching. The one that made the most sense was this:
if (img_user_image.ImageUrl.Length > 0)
{
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img_user_image.ImageUrl.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", ""));
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@user_image", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = bytes.ToArray();
}

I have tried removing the base64 header and setting bytes to be an array. But I am not saving the ASP:Image to the database.
I am not "just uploading" the file so using the FileUpload methods don't help. I figure I need to convert to a MemoryStream, but how do I get the ASP:Image into the memory stream? Everything I tried, failed.
When loading the ASP:Image object from a file upload, it works like a champ
if (fileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    intFileSize = fileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength;
    byte[] input = new byte[intFileSize - 1];
    input = FileUpload1.FileBytes;
    img_postedFile.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," +    Convert.ToBase64String(input.ToArray(), 0, input.ToArray().Length);
}

Where img_postedFile is an ASP:Image object. And saving from the uploaded image is easy peezy too!
SQL = "INSERT INTO tblImages (Name, Size, ImageData) " +
      "VALUES (@file_name, @file_size, @image_file)";
cs = DBAccess.get_cs();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, new SqlConnection(cs));
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(SQL, cmd.Connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@file_name", FileUpload1.FileName));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@file_size", intFileSize));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@image_file", input));

cmd.Connection.Open();
int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Connection.Close();

But that's not what I need to do. Now I need to save that ASP image file to the database, later in processing and not while uploading.
Googling has me going in circles and not getting to a solution. Surely there must be a way (possibly pathetically simple) to read a displayed ASP:Image and store it to a SQL Server database.
I'm hoping I'm just not asking the question correctly. Help!
Thanks in advance.

When you say it is "not saving", do you get error messages? What happens?

I think you need to read the image file contents using FileStream. Image class does not store byte stream.

I am not getting error messages, just not able to save the image out to something I can use to load it to a SQL server database.

Are you saying that I need to take an image off the page, and save it to a FileStream to be able to convert it to a byte[] so it can be uploaded to SQL? That seems counterproductive but nonetheless, can you give an example of the image to FileStream you propose? Please and Thank you.

Well, you can most certainly reference + use + enjoy use of the ImageURL of that Imagecontrol once you set it to your base64 image string.
However, keep in mind the upload control (including filename) ONLY persists on the FIRST post-back. So, your code that attempts to use filename, or file length etc. ALSO needs to be saved (persisted) for later use. So, now your attempts to "deal with things later" is not all that great of a choice.
So, you can most certainly get/grab/use/enjoy the ImageURL once it been set. Do keep in mind that since your sending the image control a "image string", then the browser can't cache the image (like it can with a valid file URL). This means on each post-back, the browser will in fact send a WHOLE copy of the image back up to the server on each post-back. This can give rise to a slow working page, and one that you not notice on your dev box (since the code, the browser and the web server and MORE important the network connection between computer and browser are ALL on the one and same computer. You thus will not notice this performance hit until you deploy to production, which then results in the web server and browser being on two different computers. Not a huge deal, but keep the above "lack" of caching in mind when you set a image to a base64 string.
So, assuming we set the image control, then this code will work to get/grab the image from that control and save it into the database.
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string fName = "ball.png";

        byte[] filebytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Image1.ImageUrl);

        // save to sql server
        string strSQL =
            @"INSERT INTO MyFiles (FileName, ImageData)
            VALUES (@File, @ImageData)";

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL,con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = fName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ImageData", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = filebytes;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

Note how we don't have to "persist" or save the file length, since when we convert the base64 string back to the byte array, then we have use of the length of the image from the array.length. And to be fair, from the SQL query, you can always get the length in bytes of that VarBinaryMax column (so, not really necessary to save that length value).
However, we do have to persist the file name, since as noted, after the subsequent file upload and post-back,  then all values of the file upload control are gone. (you have ONE chance on the post-back to save the file, get file name etc., each additional post-back will result in that FileUpLoad control being empty. As a result, I do suggest saving the file RIGHT after the file upload into the database. (and then persist the PK id of the row just added if you need to later add additional information like comments or whatever).
Also note, when working with a binary column, you REALLY want to use strong typed SQL parameters, and not let .net "guess" the parameter (column) type.
So, really nothing stopping you from grabbing the base64 string from the image control, converting back to a byte array, and then saving into the database.
